# Bluetooth api for surface pro 3 windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, bluetooth, surface

I have a bluetooth button from Radius networks.  The builtin - "add a bluetooth device" finds it every time.

I need the api or a stack that I can use to do from my app.  I am doing this in c#. the library 32 feet is not compatible

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Dn264587.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enumerate RFCOMM Bluetooth devices attached to a device, do:

```
var DEVICE_ID = new Guid("{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"); //Enter your device's RFCOMM service id (try to find it on manufactorer's website
var services = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(
        RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(
            RfcommServiceId.FromUuid(DEVICE_ID)));
```

To connect to a the first available device, do:

```
if (services.Count > 0) 
{
   var service = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(services[0].Id);
   //Open a socket to the bluetooth device for communication. Use the socket to communicate using the device's API
   var socket = new StreamSocket();
   await socket.ConnectAsync(service.ConnectionHostName, service.ConnectionServiceName, SocketProtectionLevel
                .BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication); //Substitue real BluetoothEncryption
}
```

To send data to the device and read data back, do:

```
var BYTE_NUM = 64 as UInt32; //Read this many bytes
IInputStream input = socket.InputStream;
IOutputStream output = socket.OutputStream;
var inputBuffer = new Buffer();
var operation = input.ReadAsync(inputBuffer, BYTE_NUM, InputStreamOptions.none);
while (!operation.Completed) Thread.Sleep(200);
inputBuffer = operation.GetResults();
var resultReader = DataReader.FromBuffer(inputBuffer);
byte[] result = new byte[BYTE_NUM];
resultReader.ReadBytes(result);
resultReader.Dispose();
//Do something with the bytes retrieved. If the Bluetooth device has an api, it will likely specify what bytes will be sent from the device
//Now time to give some data to the device
byte[] outputData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello, Bluetooth Device. Here's some data! LALALALALA");
IBuffer outputBuffer = outputData.AsBuffer(); //Neat method, remember to include System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime
operation = output.WriteAsync(outputBuffer);
while (!operation.Completed) Thread.Sleep(200);
await output.FlushAsync(); //Now the data has really been written
```

This will work for all RFCOMM (normal) bluetooth devices, if your device uses Bluetooth Low Energy please use the corresponding GATT classes.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattdeviceservice.aspx   again it seems you uwp.   i want to this outside of uwp